# Total comments from multiple rows MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sum

I have to sort the movies by comments so.. I tried something but I failed.

Well...

I have 2 tables

**1 - movies**

```
id -- name
 1     XX
 2     YY
```

**2 - episodes**

mid -> movie id from first table

eid -> episode id

```
id -- mid -- eid -- comments
 1     1      1       4
 2     1      2       2
 3     1      3       2
 4     2      1       1
 5     2      2       1
```

and I tried with

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(comments) AS sum_comments, COUNT(mid) AS count_mid FROM episodes ORDER BY sum_comments DESC");
while($arr = mysql_fetch_array($q))
{
    echo $arr['count_mid']." - ".$arr['sum_comments']."<br/>";
}

Output: 5 - 10

Excepted: 1 - 8
          2 - 2
```

Thank you very much !!

Comment: where are the comments stored?

Comment: Try - SELECT SUM(comments) AS sum_comments, mid FROM episodes GROUP BY mid ORDER BY sum_comments DESC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select mid,sum(comments) as TotalCommentCount from episodes 
group by mid   order by  mid
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT mid,sum(comments) AS no_comment FROM episodes 
GROUP BY mid ORDER BY no_comment..
```

Comment: Ahh similar answer alreay posted 30 sec ago...:)